# Expanding Shell Variables in Node.js

Tags: node.js

Suppose in the local environment we have that `$VAR` expands to `/path/to/var`.

Then how can I take advantage of this in node.js? In particular, suppose we have:

```
var str = "$VAR/is/here"
```

Then how can we obtain a `strExpanded` such that

```
var strExpanded = neededNodeFunction(str);
console.log(strExpanded); // "/path/to/var/is/here"
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env

For example:

```
var str = process.env.VAR + "/is/here"
```

---

**Edit**:
I'd look for npm module which does this in the first place. Then eventually fall back to tinkering something similar to

```
neededNodeFunction = str => Object.keys(process.env)
  .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length) // sort it by length so 'VAR1' gets before 'VAR'
  .reduce((str, key) => {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(`\\$${key}`, 'g'), process.env[key])
  }, str)
```

Comment: How could one make a function which scans a string for $VARs and calls process.env.VAR that way?

Comment: `neededNodeFunction` fails in case there are overlapping environment variables. I.E.: `$VAR1/file` will return `$VAR` + `1` + `/file` in case both `$VAR` and `$VAR1` are defined.

Comment: that's why I would look for npm module in the first place, and then **tinker** with that snippet :)

Comment: Maybe try to sort `Object.keys(process.env)` by length?

Answer (score 0):

```
var util = require('util');
var str = util.format('%s/is/here', process.env.VAR);
```

No npm library necessary. If this is supposed to be part of a path or similar, look at path.join:

```
var path = require('path');
var str = path.join(process.env.VAR, 'is', 'here');
```

path.join is native and takes platform into account (converts to backslash on windows, forwardslash on linux/osx/etc), and I highly encourage you to utilize this instead of substitution.

If you REALLY really (**still highly discouraged**) want to use variable substitution because that string is fed from another system that was coded by Perl, PHP or whatever other language that use that syntax, you can use something like this:

```
str.replace(/\$[a-z\d_]+/ig, function (match) {
  var sub = process.env[match.substring(1)];
  return sub || match;
})
```

Do note that this needs to be polished to handle all variations of env variables that you might find, according to the standards. Can probably not begin with number, etc etc.